# Integrate : $\int(\sin x+\cos x)^ndx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

**Problem :** $$\int(\sin x+\cos x)^n\ dx$$

I am not getting any clue how to integrate this. Please help . I will be grateful to you. Thanks.

Comment: It is done using reduction formula.
Hope it helps!!
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oH66.jpg)

Comment: Hi @Faizah, welcome to the site. Please make yourself familiar with $\LaTeX$ and type that answer with it. As is, the link in your answer may become obsolete and hence your answer, too. Best,

Answer (score 11):

**Hint:** We have 
$$\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\pi/4).$$
Now use the usual [Reduction Formula.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae)